# Cakephp 2.0.4 bake error

Tags: php, cakephp

I tried bake with Cakephp 2.0.4 stable with 'cake bake' command
But it's giving me below errors...

```
Unable to set console path for app/Console.
CakePHP is on your `include_path`. CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH will be set, but commented out.
Unable to set CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH, you should change it in /home/wmetools/public_html/security/app/Console/myapp/webroot/index.php
Project baked but with some issues..
Your database configuration was not found. Take a moment to create one.
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Are you running the command:  "Console/cake bake" from within the app directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant to say

> CakePHP is **not** on your include_path

** Code from the webroot/index.php file **

> For ease of development CakePHP uses PHP's include_path.  If you
>   cannot modify your include_path set this value.

Setting the include path will get rid of this error. There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Edit your php ini file (on wamp this would be WAMPMENU->PHP->php.ini)

[Better Description on how to.](http://support.modwest.com/content/5/98/en/how-do-i-set-php-include_path.html)

or

**// THIS METHOD IS NOT RECOMMENDED FOR THIS SITUATION**

```
1. ini_set("include_path", ".:../:./include:../include");
```

If you do not want to mess with all that, just set the include path manually in the index.php file.